# Sql Server FileStream: Architecture for document and image

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2, hierarchical-data

In my project i want use sql server filestream for file document like pdf,docx, excel, and also for image file.
In generally for file document i use a single table.

My question is for image i have to use another table or it's ok to use the same table?

Thank!

Comment: So, Where is the question??

Comment: I explained my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store your files with filestream, you can use a single table for that.
I don't see any conditions for having multiple tables for different file types in your question.